# worker_threads with node.js in nwjs

Tags: node.js, web-worker, worker, nwjs, worker-thread

worker_threads with node.js in nwjs (v0.77.0) crashes without error message

Here a list which versions work and where you can find the crash. It started with version v0.69.1

- 0.77.0 ⛔
- 0.76.1 ⛔

...

- 0.70.0 ⛔
- 0.69.1 ⛔
- 0.69.0 ✅
- 0.68.1 ✅

...

Here is my small example:

Server.js:

```
const wt = require('node:worker_threads');
try{
    setTimeout(function(){
        let w = new wt.Worker("./workerFile.js");
    }, 500);
}catch(err){
    console.log(err);
}
```

workerFile.js:

```
console.log("START WEB WORKER");
const fs=require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('output.txt', "hello world");
```

package.json:

```
{
    "additional_trust_anchors": [],
    "app_name": "TestWebWorker",
    "chromium-args": "--enable-node-worker",
    "js-flags": "--enable-node-worker",
    "main": "index.html",
    "name": "testwebworker",
    "node-main": "Server.js",
    "node-remote": [],
    "nodejs": true,
    "single-instance": false,
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "webexe_settings": {
        "blacklist": "",
        "custom_script": "",
        "download_dir": "",
        "force_download": false,
        "linux-x32": false,
        "linux-x64": false,
        "mac-x64": false,
        "nw_compression_level": 0,
        "nw_version": "0.77.0",
        "output_pattern": "",
        "sdk_build": true,
        "uncompressed_folder": true,
        "whitelist": "",
        "windows-x32": false,
        "windows-x64": true
    },
    "webkit": {
        "double_tap_to_zoom_enabled": false,
        "plugin": false
    },
    "window": {
        "always_on_top": false,
        "as_desktop": true,
        "frame": true,
        "fullscreen": false,
        "id": "TestwebWorker",
        "kiosk": false,
        "kiosk_emulation": false,
        "position": "center",
        "resizable": true,
        "show": true,
        "show_in_taskbar": true,
        "title": "TestwebWorker",
        "transparent": false,
        "visible": true,
        "visible_on_all_workspaces": true
    }
}
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
            switch (event.which) {
                case 119: // F8
                    console.warn(event.key);
                    chrome.developerPrivate.openDevTools({ renderViewId: -1, renderProcessId: -1, extensionId: chrome.runtime.id });
                    break;
            }
        })
    </script>
    <p style="color: black">TEST WORKER</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Is it a bug in NWJS (https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/8082) ?

Or am I missing something??
PLEASE HELP!
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if it works with old version(s) of NW.js but fails with latest version, open an Issue in GitHub. That said, this one appears to have already been reported: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/8082

Comment: Thanks for the post. Yes I have already reported the bug.

But I find it surprising that not others encounter this error and I wonder if I have not done something wrong